# TCP Connection Life time

Tags: tcp, connection

I know that the TCP is connection oriented. But if I set up a forwarding server(syslog server for example) which forwards logs on TCP, is the connection always on or whenever the logs are forwarded to a server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server configuration.
Say you are working on Linux, you can use the command

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

to check your current keepalive value in seconds.